# PHP, jQuery SQL Autocomplete - Show firstname/surname to user but have the actual value as ID?

Tags: php, jquery, sql, arrays, autocomplete

I've recently followed a guide on how to create 'City' autocomplete search using the Twitter typeahead Jquery tool, which I adapted to suit my own problem of searching for student names. The autocomplete solution works correctly, so that when you search a students name, it predicts which you want to use. However I now face another problem which I can't figure out!

The autocomplete textbox returns the Firstname Surname of the student, however I now want to be able to search a table based on this value which needs to be student_id, not firstname/surname.

My question is, can I show the firstname surname to the person searching, but the actual value being stored (hidden) is the student_id? Which I can then use for a select query.

Currently looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cCySZ.png)

My code is currently:

PHP

```
    if (isset($_REQUEST['query'])) {
        $query = $_REQUEST['query'];
        $sql = mysql_query ("SELECT firstname, surname,student_id FROM students WHERE
firstname LIKE '%{$query}%' OR surname LIKE '%{$query}%'");
        $array = array();
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
            $array[] = array (
                'label' => $row['firstname'].', '.$row['firstname'],
                'value' => $row['firstname'].', '.$row['firstname'],
            );
        }
        //RETURN JSON ARRAY
        echo json_encode ($array);
    }
```

Script

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function() {

            $('input.city').typeahead({
                name: 'city',
                remote: 'studentsearch.php?query=%QUERY',
        limit:10

            });

        })
    </script>
```

HTML

```
    <form>
            <h1>Student Name</h1>
            <input type="text" name="city" size="30" class="city" placeholder="Enter 

Students First or Last Name">
        <input type="submit" name="search" class="city" value="Search">
        </form>
```

Comment: Are you using this [typeahead](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/blob/master/doc/jquery_typeahead.md#options) library?

Comment: Hi Terminus, thanks for the reply. I'm using the library included in the guide which was http://netsh.pp.ua/upwork-demo/1/js/typeahead.js.

Comment: Just add another element to the array with the student_id, then use that on return - I dunno the Typeahead-library, but I would assume they have the possibility to create custom functions for return values - read the docs.